# Is a buffer necessary when using QTcpSocket?

Tags: c++, qt

I was curious if it is necessary to create my own buffer and then read in the data from the `QTcpSocket` on each `readyRead()` signal. I would usually think it is a good idea, but I have seen on a few different websites (and maybe even the Qt website, I can't remember) that using a buffer is completely unnecessary and it is a better idea to just return if a complete packet isn't ready yet, and wait until the next `readyRead()` signal. Does `QTcpSocket` take care of growing it's internal buffer or does it have a max? I know it might also depend on the size of the packet, so let's say the max is about 150kb.

Answer (score 1):

QTcpSocket manages an internal, unbound buffer (see `QAbstractSocket::setReadBufferSize`). So there's technically no need of keeping your own separate buffer.